# Linq Looping through Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I've got a complete blank at the moment, but I am wonder how I would do this:

I need to insert linq data into the following, but im not sure how to get 2 sets of data from a for look in link.

```
<ul>
<li>database value one</li>
<li>database value two</li>
<ul>
```

Here's an example I've whipped up showing what I'm trying to do:

```
foreach (blog_post h in recentBlogData)
        {

            recentString = recentString + "<ul>";

            DateTime blogDate = DateTime.Parse(h.blogPublishDate.ToString());

            recentString = recentString +
                "<li>" +
                    "<div class=\"date\"><span>" + blogDate.ToString("%d") + "</span>" + blogDate.ToString("MMM").ToLower() + "</div>" +
                    "<strong><a href=\"" + s.getURL("SITE") + "/news/" + h.blogPostId + "/" + g.clean(h.blogPostTitle).ToLower() + "\">" + h.blogPostTitle + "</a></strong>" +
                    "<div class=\"cl\"></div>" +
                    "<p>" + h.blogReadMore + "<br />" +
                    "</p>" +
                "</li>";

            //this needs to be the next record.

            recentString = recentString +
                "<li>" +
                    "<div class=\"date\"><span>" + blogDate.ToString("%d") + "</span>" + blogDate.ToString("MMM").ToLower() + "</div>" +
                    "<strong><a href=\"" + s.getURL("SITE") + "/news/" + h.blogPostId + "/" + g.clean(h.blogPostTitle).ToLower() + "\">" + h.blogPostTitle + "</a></strong>" +
                    "<div class=\"cl\"></div>" +
                    "<p>" + h.blogReadMore + "<br />" +
                    "</p>" +
                "</li>";

            recentString = recentString + "</ul>";
        }
```

Cheers

Comment: would a `<asp:Repeater>` not suffice?

Comment: So for each iteration it will append both the current and the next one? everything will show twice... Please explain how exactly you want the end result to look like.

Comment: Never use the repeater before, I'll look it up thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding all data in go you will need to access it one by one as for loop will give you like this:

```
StringBuilder recentstring = new StringBuilder();
recentstring.Append("<ul>");
foreach (blog_post h in recentBlogData)
        {   
            DateTime blogDate = DateTime.Parse(h.blogPublishDate.ToString());

            recentstring.Append("<li>");
                            recentstring.Append("<div class=\"date\"><span>");
                            recentstring.Append(blogDate.ToString("%d"));
                            recentstring.Append("</span>");
                            recentstring.Append(blogDate.ToString("MMM").ToLower());
                            recentstring.Append("</div>");
                            recentstring.Append("<strong><a href=\"");
                            recentstring.Append(s.getURL("SITE") + "/news/" + h.blogPostId + "/" + g.clean(h.blogPostTitle).ToLower() + "\">" + h.blogPostTitle)
                            recentstring.Append("</a></strong>");
                            recentstring.Append("<div class=\"cl\"></div>");
                            recentstring.Append("<p>" + h.blogReadMore + "<br />");
                            recentstring.Append("</p></li>");
        }
recentstring.Append("</ul>");
```

Comment: Ugh. Please change this to use a StringBuilder!

Comment: and also no need to concatenate values. use `AppendFormat` - that's what its there for.

Comment: +1 yeah i totally agree... changed it.. was in hurry before..so just copy paste and edit

Comment: I see what you mean I will starting using StringBuilder from now on.

Lets say I have 6 values, but they are split 3 times, <ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul> <ul><li>3</li><li>4</li></ul> etc.. If I'm on the right track the above would give be 1 set of <ul> with the data inside...

Comment: obviously you will need to know the depth of your elements and do nested foreach loops

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, using `<asp:Repeater>` would definitely be better than concatenating strings containing HTML. Anyway, using LINQ you can write for example something like this:

```
var q = 
  from h in recentBlogData
  let blogDate = DateTime.Parse(h.blogPublishDate.ToString());
  select "<li>" +
           "<div class=\"date\"><span>" + blogDate.ToString("%d") + "</span>" 
              + blogDate.ToString("MMM").ToLower() + "</div>" +
           "<strong><a href=\"" + s.getURL("SITE") + "/news/" + h.blogPostId
              + "/" + g.clean(h.blogPostTitle).ToLower() + "\">" 
              + h.blogPostTitle + "</a></strong>" +
           "<div class=\"cl\"></div>" +
           "<p>" + h.blogReadMore + "<br />" +
           "</p>" + "</li>";
var result = "<ul>" + String.Concat(q) + "</ul>";
```

However, this won't be very fast, so using `StringBuilder` would be probably better option than concatenating strings. (But still, `Repeater` or something similar is the way to go).

Comment: Thanks Tomas, appreciate the advice. I'll look into Repeater and StringBuilder.